# Let $p$ be a prime. Compute the Galois group of the polynomial $f(X)=X^p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Compute the Galois group of the polynomial $f(X)=X^p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

A result I known: Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $0$ and $L$ be the splitting field of that polynonomial. Then the Galois group of $L/K$ is a cyclic group.

What should I do then?

Thank for support.

Comment: what would be roots of $x^p-1$?

Comment: $ L=\mathbb{Q}(1,\omega,\omega^2,.....,\omega^{p-1}) $

Comment: So, how many possibilities do you have for image of $\omega$...

Comment: $p$ possibilities

Comment: can you really map $w$ to $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: call $\;K\;$ the splitting field of $\;f(x)\;$ over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_p:=e^{2\pi i/p}) -- \;\text{since}\;\;\langle\,\zeta_p\,\rangle=\{\text{all the $p$-th roots of unit in}\;\Bbb C\}\\
\bullet&\;\;\forall\;k=1,2,\ldots,p-1\;,\;\;\zeta_p\mapsto \zeta_p^k\;\;\text{is an automorphism of}\;\;K/\Bbb Q\\
\bullet&\;\;[K:\Bbb Q]=\phi(p)=p-1\end{align*}$$